# Insert whitespace between individual output items when returning data($variable) in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, whitespace

I have transformed a rather messy HMTL document with many unnecessary `<span>` tags etc. into an XML file just to be able to read the data.

The HTML file contains 100 items with standardized bibliographic information.

Using the following query in XQuery...

```
 for $v in doc("Geburtsbrief1-100.xml")
 return data($v)
```

... I get an output structured like this for each item:

```
SIGNATUR:G / 1630 M�rz 20Regest:Pforzheim,1630.03.20Geburtsbrieff�rdenMaurerundSteinmetzHansRuckisservonPforzheim.Aussteller:StadtPforzheim.S.derStadt.Datierung:20.03.1630Formalbeschreibung (bei
Urkunden):Ausfertigung.Perg.Provenienz:StadtMainzPersonenindex:Ruckisser, HansOrtsindex:Pforzheim
```

I am using BaseX and XQuery version 3.1 to run my query.

The XML structure of the "place" information in the result string above looks like this:

```
<tr class="ergebniserfassungzeile" id="org3_9_0">
<th id="org3_9_0F" class="fnam" axis="Feldname">
<div class="ergebniserfassungfeldname">Provenienz:</div>
</th>
<td colspan="2" id="org3_9_0I" axis="Feldinhalt" class="tdfinh">
<div id="div3_9" class="ergebniserfassungfeldinhalt"><a class="h"
title="" href="javascript:h('5%20Stadt')">Stadt</a> <a class="h"
title="" href="javascript:h('5%20Mainz')">Mainz</a></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

All other types of data (information on people, the materiality of the document, the content etc.) have the exact same table structure with the exact same tags, attributes and attribute values such as "Feldinhalt". This is why I at least need to capture full `<tr class="ergebniserfassungzeile">` nodes to still make sense of the results I get.

In terms of data, the complete `data($v)` is perfect, and I don't mind that German special characters are messed up. But I would love to see **whitespace** between all words. As virtually each word is framed by one of the `<span>` tags in the original HTML, this output is technically correct.

Is there a way to tell XQuery to **add additional whitespace** after returning the data in each document tag? All tutorials I have found so far explained how to remove whitespace, but I want to do the opposite.

Comment: So which structure does your XML have? Can't you select any elements or text nodes instead of calling `data` on the complete document node? Also which XQuery processor, which XQuery version is that?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I will edit my initial request accordingly as the comment section is limited.

Comment: So the data is structured but you can't select anything but the complete document? That doesn't make sense. Also there seems to be whitespace between words, perhaps you just need to configure BaseX to not strip it.

Comment: As I stated in my edit above, the lowest I can go in the file structure without breaking the context is "ergebniserfassungszeile" (see code snippet above), but that would not solve the whitespace issue. In some RARE cases, such as in the archival ID at the beginning of my sample result string, the original HTML has whitespace, indeed, but it is super rare. If the HTML was better structured, you would expect something like "Provenienz" to be an attribute or attribute value, and "Stadt Mainz" the value of that particular tag. Unfortunately, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know XBase but I think this should do the trick:

```
xquery for $v in doc("Geburtsbrief1-100.xml")
return (fn:data($v), ' ')
```

Comment: I tried this already, but that only gives me whitespace at the end of the "ergebniserfassungzeile", while the actual result terms, which are in individual tags within, are still "merged".

Answer (score 0):

The sample data you have presented contains white space so simply selecting that would output the white space between words e.g. at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuPs7 the result of

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';

.
```

is

```
Provenienz:


Stadt Mainz
```

So I think you might want to ensure that BaseX is not chopping off white space during parsing.

As for the question in general, if you have a single string like `data()` called on a single document node would give you, there is no magic to insert separators.

On the other hand, you can select down to the text node level and insert an item separator or you can use string-join e.g.

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator ' ';

//text()
```

or

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';

string-join(//text(), ' ')
```

Comment: Trying the "text" method is a good idea, thanks a lot. I will give it a go later today and let you know what happened.

Comment: I tried this but got the same result that I received when calling "data" in my original function: `xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace c="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare variable $file:=doc('Geburtsbrief1-100.xml');
declare option output:method 'text';
for $v in $file//c:html//c:body
return $v`

Comment: The problem seems to be that I am not applying the output method "text" correctly. But if I leave "for" and "return" out and just use "." like you did in your example, I get an error notification.

Comment: An HTML document usually has exactly one `body` element so even if you do a `for $v in $file//c:html//c:body return $v` you select exactly one item and you won't get any separator. Select leaf elements or select text nodes e.g. `//*[not(*)]` or `//text()`.

Comment: I did this (which is only calling the info in the right column of the HTML table on the lowest level of the file structure): `xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace c="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare variable $file:=doc('Geburtsbrief1-100_test.xml');
declare option output:method 'text';
$file//c:html//c:body//c:tag//c:tag//c:table//c:tbody//c:tr//c:td//c:tag//text()` But the results are still merged in a string without whitespace. Will try inserting another separator into the input file now.

Comment: If you select more than one item, to have a separator, you also need to declare it with e.g. `declare option output:item-separator ' ';`. Or use `string-join` e.g. `$file//c:html//c:body//c:tag//c:tag//c:table//c:tbody//c:tr//c:td//c:tag//text() => string-join(' ')`

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I figured something really simple out just now, manipulating the input XML before running XQuery. Will post the solution as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for me was to alter the X(H)TML input file before running XQuery. As all the relevant data are in `<tag>` tags (a random name I chose when the original `<div>` tags wouldn't parse), I could open the input file in an XML editor and simply replace `<tag` by `<tag xml:space="preserve"`.

I now get data output like this when calling `data` in XQuery even on higher-level nodes:

```
Provenienz:

Stadt Mainz

Personenindex:

Schwarz, Hermann
```

Comment: I don't see how editing the XML input is a solution to doing something with XQuery code but the approach you have chosen suggests that you simply want BaseX to not chop whitespace i.e. to set https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#CHOP to false.

Comment: My focus is not a particular tool or method but a certain result. I normally use Python to analyse XML files but wanted to check out what BaseX / XQuery can do for me. So thanks for sending the link to the "chop" options in BaseX. I should definitely set this to "false" for all future operations.